# Best practices for resolving statically javascript dependencies

Tags: javascript, dependencies, preprocessor

It's quite sad I have to ask this question in April 2012, but I know quite few approaches to the problem.

So, I want a tool for **statically** compiling javascript files, resolving dependencies.
To be more precise I want such tool (let's call it `sometool`) which can do following:

- scan a folder, find all `*.js` files
- parse this files and find some very simple **synchronous** and 100% js-compliant directive. By synchronous I mean that there is no such thing like passing onload handler - it's only about static text preprocessing. By 100% js-compliant I mean that it looks it's looks like a comment from js point of view - something like `// @include`
- resolve paths used in include directive, using some config **which can be customized**.
- substitute all include with real output and put it into a separate folder.

I do realize that all this sounds obvious to most of you, but javascripters nowadays understand something slightly different while talking about dependency managing - see [require.js](http://requirejs.org/), for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a look at [sprockets](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets). It can bundle and pack JavaScript files and supports includes. <strike>You might have to write some boilerplate code though.</strike> There seems to be a script that allows sprocket to be run from command line bundled with it. And it's in Ruby. Don't know if this is a problem.

Comment: tested it and this is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you for advice.

Answer (score 2):

There actually is one answer, its name is: [`Apache ANT`](http://ant.apache.org/)

ANT like *Make*, is a tool which can do almost any job for you. Concatenating files, stripping, reading files/foldes, minifiying, etc. etc. Instructions are done via *.xml* files, many jobs are already present but of course you can write your own jobs.

That way, you can have a perfect **static build process**. Personally I use it on severval bases. Have a look as example: https://github.com/jAndreas/typeof-NaN-2.0/tree/master/build

I'm not resolving javascript dependencies the way you described, but I do it with stylesheet dependencies there (replacing `@import` lines with actual files). So its a fairly easy task to do the same with javascript files. Also, last step in those build scripts are to copy the fresh generated files into my *Apache website* directory, its indeed one static build process and you're done.

Don't be scared about the filesize, I modified an existent config file from the *HTML5 boiler plate* there. I actually could shrink that file to 10% size, removing all optional builds.

Comment: @limelights: I would agree, but the OP explicitly ruled that out.

Comment: @jAndy, thank you for this answer. I can hardly imagine an easy, out-of-the-box way to use ant for building js. the link you've provided does not dissuades me)))

Comment: @shabunc: as an example, I log into my bash and do type `cd /project/name/build` followed by `ant build`. Thats it. Then ANT will do this: concatenate all js files, all css files, resolve any css dependency, strip debug messages, minify all js/css/html, create unique-hash keys for js and css files and replace the `src` attribute with that names (also rename the filenames to that).

Comment: Personally I wouldn't use ANT but Make. This however is a just a personal preference. Simply search your files for the import statement and replace it with the contents of the file referenced. Be aware of circular references though!

Comment: @DanielBaulig: yep nothing wrong with using *Make* instead. I guess it has the some amount of options that ANT has. The nice thing about ANT is that it offers alot of common stuff as ready-to-go job also, plus it runs on java and is pretty os compatible.

Comment: @jAndy, well, I even can imagine using maven for the same purposes. On the other hand, I can imagine using something far more simpler - like perl script. But somewhere in between there must be, I just can not believe is does not exist, some balanced solution. For example, you've mentions css includes - for this purpose nowadays can use sass. That kind of tool I'm looking for.